# Trigger function only after multiple select is finished

Tags: angularjs, multiple-select

I was curious what would be the best way to accomplish this.

I have a multiple selection select box.
I'm triggering a function on its ng-change event.
This is not good for me in one specific case where redirection occurs after the first selection in the box.
I want to be able to let the user makes as many selections as he wishes and redirect after that.
What would be the best way to implement this?
Is there maybe some other ng event that I can use, or maybe do some specific checking in the function that triggers on ng-change event?
Thanks

Comment: How do you know at what point the user has finished selecting as many options as they want? Unless there is a hard limit, you would have to add a button or some way for the user to tell you that they have finished making their selections.

Comment: Hm, I cannot that's the point.
There is no limit in the selection.
The idea of Yours is fine if I would have the button.
Maybe have some function check some flag variable in the triggered function?

Comment: It depends entirely on your application use cases. You could consider removing the ng-change and always performing the action when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

tie the `select options` to an `ng-model` and provide a `submit button` and let the `button` trigger a function that reads in which options are selected and act accordingly.